# Promesa de AngularJS devuelve arreglo vacío

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promesas

Buen día, estoy trabajando con lectura de archivos XML del lado del cliente los cuales envío a una función situada en un servicio AngularJS y éste al terminar de leer su contenido me devuelve un objeto del archivo y a su vez la función mostrada a continuación agrega la respuesta a una colección de objetos.

Sin embargo en el success de la llamada a `$scope.fillCFDIArray()` trato de imprimir el resultado pero me aparece en consola un arreglo nulo como este `Array[]...` pero a clicar en el sí que contiene los objetos, esto es algo confuso, ya que necesito recorrer el arreglo resultado pero al estar vacío el ciclo for simplemente no entra.

```
    $scope.fillCFDIArray = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filesXML.length; i++) {
            $funcs.readXMLFile($scope.filesXML[i]).then(function successCallBack(response) {
                result.push(response);
            }, function errorCallBack(response) {
                console.log(response);
                deferred.reject(response);
                return deferred.promise;
            });
            if (i == $scope.filesXML.length - 1) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
                return deferred.promise;
            };
        };
    };

        $scope.fillCFDIArray().then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);//Esta linea en el debug del navegador me aparece Array[]
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                console.log(response[i]);//Nunca entra aqui puesto que interpreta que el 
//arreglo esta vacio; pero si le doy clic en el 
//debug de firefox sí me aparecen los elementos de ese arreglo
            };
        }, function errorCallBack(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Si alguien tiene idea de lo que sucede le agradecería sus comentarios.

**UPDATE**

Añado la funcion encargada de leer el archivo, la cual tengo dentro de un servicio AngularJS:

```
this.readXMLFile = function (file) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (element) {
            var xmlText = element.target.result;
            var xml2Json = new X2JS();
            var jsonObj = xml2Json.xml_str2json(xmlText);
            var comprobante = {};
            comprobante = jsonObj.Comprobante;
            deferred.resolve(comprobante);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    } else {
        deferred.reject('El archivo no pudo ser procesado');
    };
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Se supone que lo que retorna esto, es un objeto JSON creado a partir del contenido del XML que se lee.
Como estoy leyendo los archivos desde un input file multiple, debo esperar que todos los archivos seleccionados sean procesados y entonces retornar un Arreglo que contiene los objetos creados a partir de cada uno de los archivos leídos.

Todo iba bien hasta que descubrí que me devuelve el arreglo vacío.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu función contiene algo como esto al inicio

```
$scope.fillCFDIArray = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
```

que es una construcción explicita de una promesa.

Esto **siempre** implica que la última linea de tu función debe ser

```
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

En tu caso esta dentro de un `if` que a su ves está dentro de un ciclo `for`

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filesXML.length; i++) {
    // ....
    if (i == $scope.filesXML.length - 1) {
        // ....
        return deferred.promise;
    };
};
```

De hecho esta linea se encuentra varias veces en tu código lo cual es un error.

Siempre debe ser algo como

```
function devuelvePromesa() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // ejecuta deferred.reject y deferred.resolve en algún lugar aquí

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Si mi intuición no me falla la funcion `$funcs.readXMLFile`, la cual no incluyes en tu pregunta, retorna también una promesa por lo que estás cayendo en el [antipatrón de construcción explicita](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern). Hay una mejor solución a tu problema, retorna `q.all` y une todas tus promesas en una sola.

```
$scope.fillCFDIArray = function () {
    var promesas = $scope.filesXML.map(function(file) {
        return $funcs.readXMLFile(file);
    });
    return $q.all(promesas);
};
```

Tampoco deberías usar `.then(function, function)`, algo como ésto hará que tu código falle

```
promise.then(function() {
    throw new Error();
}, function() {
    // El callback nunca se ejecutará
});
```

Siempre usa `catch`

```
promise.then(function() {
    throw new Error();
}).catch(function() {
    // El callback manejará el error apropiadamente
});
```

Lee [el antipatrón .then(success, fail)](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-.then)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me ayudo a estructurar de mejor forma la funcion.

Comment: @KikinRdz Tu respuesta aceptada es un antipatrón. **NUNCA** debes pasar una promesa por parámetros, en su lugar **siempre** debes hacer que la llamada a la función **retorne** la promesa. Eso sólo conduce al [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) que es para lo que las promises fueron creadas . Creo que en tu caso deberías refactorizar todo tu código para usar `q.all` mira mi update. Solo debes construir explicitamente las promesas cuando realmente no te queda otro remedio

Comment: Gracias @devconcept , leeré el articulo que comentas para comprender mejor el manejo de promesas.

Comment: solo deseo agradecer de nuevo @devconcept es increible como algo tan sencillo parece ser tan complicado hasta que alguien aclara tu vision de las cosas, desconozco si tienes cursos en la red pero si no es asi deberias considerarlo se nota que tienes mucha experiencia en el lenguaje. Un saludo desde Mexico

Answer (score 1):

Según veo, tienes un problema de control de flujo asincrono. es decir, no esperas la respuesta antes de tratar procesar los resultados. este error es muy común cuando se trabaja con javascript y con promesas.
te voy a explicar usando tu codigo:

```
$scope.fillCFDIArray = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filesXML.length; i++) {
// Aquí lees el archivo xml en la posición i, pero es una llamado a una función y tiene una promesa, por lo tanto el for no se detiene, el continua.
            $funcs.readXMLFile($scope.filesXML[i]).then(function successCallBack(response) {
                result.push(response);
            }, function errorCallBack(response) {
                console.log(response);
                deferred.reject(response);
                return deferred.promise;
            });
// Aquí validas si el for ya terminó de ejecutarse, PERO!!! esto no asegura que todas las promesas generadas para la lectura del XML ya terminaron... entonces aquí radica el problema. porque el for es mucho mas rapido que la lectura del XML y cuando llega a este punto el array "result" sigue vacio.
            if (i == $scope.filesXML.length - 1) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
                return deferred.promise;
            };
        };
    };
```

cuando lo revisas desde el debug de firefox, todo parece normal... la razón es que en ese momento todas las promesas ya se resolvieron.

Yo te recomiendo que uses una función recursiva. asi te aseguras de leer la siguente linea solo cuando ya se proceso la linea actual. algo asi:

```
 // promise: promesa.
// result: el array que quieres llenar.
// pos: posición de lectura del XML,
// xml: xml para lees
function readXML(promise, result, pos, xml){

     // validas si ya terminó de recorrer el XML y resuelves las promesa.
    if(result.length >= pos){
        promise(resolve(result));
        return;
    }
    // procesas la posicion "pos" del xml
    $funcs.readXMLFile($scope.filesXML[i]).then(function successCallBack(response) {
        result.push(response);
        // solo cuando se procesó la liea, vuelves a llamar la misma funcion de forma recursiva con incremento en la posición.
        pos++;
        readXml(promise, result, pos, xml);
    }, function errorCallBack(response) {
        // si hay error, llamas al reject de la promesa y no hay mas llamados recursivos.
        promise.reject(result);
    });

}
```

Para llamar a la función la primera ves:

```
var promise = $q.defer();
var result = [];
// llamas a la funcion con los valores iniciales.
readXml(promise, result, 0, $scope.filesXML);

// luego defines la respuesta de la promesa.
promise.hen(function(res){
    // .. aquí haces lo que necesitas.
}, function(err){
    //. ocurrío un error en proceso.
})
```

yo no acostumbro a usar promesas para estos casos, me gustan mas los callbacks. (para estos casos)
Sin embargo te hice el ejercicio con promesas.

No lo he probado, seguro tengo algunos errores, pero quería ilustrarte la forma como deberias implementarlo.

Saludos.

Comment: Con algunas adecuaciones utilicé esta respuesta para resolver el problema. Agradezco el apoyo de ambas respuestas pero ésta en particular me ayuda con el detalle que tenía.